# Scrapy OpenSSL exceptions.TypeError: data must be a byte string

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Scrapy 0.24.5.
I run a simple scrapy crawl:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import scrapy
from bot.items import GoogleItem

class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.google.com/search?q=2pac',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
        issuance = sel.xpath("//div[@id='search']")
        items = []

        for issue in issuance:
            item = GoogleItem()
            item['title'] = issuance.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]/a/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            item['url'] = issuance.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]/a/@href').extract()
```

And have an error:

```
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: bot)
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, django
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bot.spiders', 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bot.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bot', 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT': 3600, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 10}
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: RandomUserAgent, ErrorMonkeyMiddleware, HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] INFO: Spider opened
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=2pac&gws_rd=cr&ei=CXnzVKOOH8TkUZapgbgC> from <GET http://www.google.com/search?q=2pac>
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=2pac&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=CXnzVKOOH8TkUZapgbgC> from <GET http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=2pac&gws_rd=cr&ei=CXnzVKOOH8TkUZapgbgC>
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [ScrapyHTTPPageGetter,client] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
            return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
            return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 59, in callWithContext
            return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 37, in callWithContext
            return func(*args,**kw)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 146, in _doReadOrWrite
            why = getattr(selectable, method)()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 177, in doWrite
            return Connection.doWrite(self)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 428, in doWrite
            result = abstract.FileDescriptor.doWrite(self)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 115, in doWrite
            l = self.writeSomeData(self.dataBuffer)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 181, in writeSomeData
            return Connection.writeSomeData(self, data)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 474, in writeSomeData
            return self.socket.send(buffer(data, 0, self.SEND_LIMIT))
          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 947, in send

        exceptions.TypeError: data must be a byte string

2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=2pac&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=CXnzVKOOH8TkUZapgbgC>: data must be a byte string
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/exception_count': 1,
         'downloader/exception_type_count/exceptions.TypeError': 1,
         'downloader/request_bytes': 984,
         'downloader/request_count': 3,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 2272,
         'downloader/response_count': 2,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 20, 39, 37, 779072),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
         'log_count/ERROR': 2,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 20, 39, 37, 157082)}
2015-03-01 22:39:37+0200 [google] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What's wrong? Thanks!
In addition, It seems that I didn't have this error before, maybe it caused by the system upgrade or maybe not.